# Script to run a program against contents of a text file

Tags: variables, batch-file, command, text-files, counter

Script to run a program against contents of a text file. But needs to run against next line in the test file everytime it runs. So using a counter to proceed to next line of text file when i run it the second time. I guess i need to grab each line depending on the count and use it as a variable in the final command. So something like below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f %%x in (somefile) do (
  set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"
  set /a Counter+=1
)
start /AFFINITY (textfile line x) [.exe]
```

Text file consists of hex numbers for cpus

4

16

5E

17E

Not sure how to better explain what i need.
Basically i need to point a process at different combinations of cpus each time a user launches the app.
So user1 goes to cpu0 and cpu1, user2 to cpu2 and cpu3 and so on.

Comment: Show a few lines from the text file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Every time through the loop the `for /f "delims="` loop will provide the next line in the loop variable.  I don't understand your question either.